# What did I do that made "weak refs processing" take 30 sec instead of 1.5 sec?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

### The story

My server is running with 24x2 processors, and the java heap is about 70 GB.
At some point after installing a new version (version-B), I saw that Full GC is taking around 30sec (stopping all threads). After enabling the XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled the weak ref processing went down to around 3-6 sec. But this is just a "Bend aid", not a cure.

> 2011-03-22T20:38:24.276+0000:
>   29540.794: [GC[YG occupancy: 5477281 K (7549760 K)]29540.794: [Rescan
>   (parallel) , 0.4083780 secs]29541.203:
>   [weak refs processing, 3.2855240
>   secs]29544.488: [class unloading,
>   0.0187270 secs]29544.507: [scrub symbol & string tables, 0.0095530
>   secs] [1 CMS-remark:
>   102801236K(114294784K)]
>   108278518K(121844544K), 3.7319690
>   secs] [Times: user=65.53 sys=0.14,
>   real=3.73 secs]

Before version-B, (and without the ParallelRefProcEnabled flag) the weak ref processing used to take around 1.5 sec. (For roughly the same load)

### The purpose:

What I'm trying to find out is, what was the change introduced version-B that caused the processing to jump from 1.5 sec to 30 sec.
There are a few changes in version-B, and no real suspect involving weak-references.

I want to change my code so it would not relay on heavy weak ref processing.

### Questions:

- I would like to understand what exactly is happening in the "weak ref processing" stage, so I can look for a suspect, or justify a code rewrite. Any good resource for reading about what exactly happens in that stage?
- What are the possible causes for long "weak refs processing"? (Number of weak references instances, number of objects holding a weak-reference, depth of reference-tree which is weakly referenced,...)

### More info:

- The CPU usage is not so high and doesn't seem to be an issue
- The GC (that includes weak reference processing) occurs about every 8 minutes.
- Running Java Sun, 1.6.0_20

I'd appreciate any response,
Thanks,
Erez.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101540/how-can-i-lower-the-weak-ref-processing-time-during-gc

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, The Reference processing time is the time it takes to determine whether a reference can be collected or not.  This should be propoprtional to the number of WeakReferences you have.

It may be that a change in data structure is possible which reduces the number of weak references dramatically. e.g. say you have a cache using Map of WeakReferences.  If this can be replaced with a WeakReference to a Map you may get the same outcome but with dramatically less references.

You may see a performance improvement with Java 6 update 24 which has a much newer JVM (about a year newer)